# How to access the clipboard contents using Playwright in Typescript

Tags: clipboard, ui-automation, playwright

I have a playwright test running in Chromium under Node.  I'm using playwright 1.19.2.  The test clicks a "Copy UUID" link, which then copies a UUID into the clipboard.  What is the best way to access the contents of the clipboard from playwright?

Comment: For Java you have library related for clipboard, maybe you have it for node also, not sure.
The another way is using random textbox , click on it and just keyboard comand
 await page.keyboard.press('Ctrl+V'); And then just get text.

Comment: Please tell how to do it in Java @GajJulije

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now there is no dedicated event for clipboard copy paste emulation. There are open incidents in the Playwright github that you can track for future references - [#8114](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/8114) , [#15860](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15860), [#13097](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13097)

The only workaround is that you can simulate the `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V` events as mentioned in the issue #8114

```
  const modifier = isMac ? 'Meta' : 'Control';
  await page.setContent(`<div contenteditable>123</div>`);
  await page.focus('div');
  await page.keyboard.press(`${modifier}+KeyA`);
  await page.keyboard.press(`${modifier}+KeyC`);
  await page.keyboard.press(`${modifier}+KeyV`);
  await page.keyboard.press(`${modifier}+KeyV`);
  expect(await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div').textContent)).toBe('123123');
```

Answer (score 6):

One could try the following, if the proposed solutions in the issues linked by @demouser123 do not work:

```js
test('copy uuid', async ({ page, context }) => {
    // Grant clipboard permissions to browser context
    await context.grantPermissions(["clipboard-read", "clipboard-write"]);
    
    /* Your test code */
    
    // Get clipboard content after the link/button has been clicked
    const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => navigator.clipboard.readText());
    const clipboardContent = await handle.jsonValue();
    
    // Check that the clipboard contains correct UUID
    expect(clipboardContent).toEqual('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually a much better way to put data in the clipboard is

```
page.evaluate("navigator.clipboard.writeText('123')")
```